# Java でのアプリ内更新ファイルアクセスの一般的な方法

Tags: java

タイトルがわかりづらくて申しわけありません。

Java で、特に JavaWebStart や Tomcat などのフレームワーク(?)などを使用せずに、単体で動作する CUI アプリを作るとします (CUI でなくても JavaFX の GUI アプリでもよいのですが)。
このとき、静的データについてはたとえば java.lang.ClassLoader#getResource などでアプリ内の **大きなファイル** や **多数のファイル群** などを参照アクセスすることができることがわかるのですが、その **大きなファイル** や **多数のファイル群** をアプリ内に動的に作成したり更新アクセスしたりするには、一般的にはどのような方法をとるものでしょうか。
ただしプロセス単位に生成消滅させる一時的なファイルではなく、アプリ単位に生成消滅させるべきファイルです。 また、データベースを別途使用するようなやや大袈裟なことも考えていません。

小さなデータであれば、java.util.prefs のようなものがあるのはわかります。理想的には Android や iOS のように参照・更新できるアプリ固有領域の概念があるとよいのですが、Java SE 自体にそのような概念はあったでしょうか？
また、Eclipse や NetBeans や Maven などで生成する標準プロジェクトの機能にもそのような考え方はできるでしょうか？

Comment: イマイチよくわかりませんが、`java.util.prefs.Preferences`がそういう用途かと思います。

Comment: 具体例として、リソースを追加ダウンロードしたりゲーム開始時にマップを生成・保存したりするゲームを想像しました。この場合素直にファイルアクセスするのではと思うのですが、「アプリ内～」「アプリ固有領域」と書かれているのはユーザーからその実体を隠したいということでしょうか？

Comment: 隠したいというよりも、そのプロジェクトをまるごと削除したり移動し易い形です。 通常ネイティブ アプリは OS によってその造りは異なってしまうとは思うのですが、 もしかしたら Java では何らかの美しい仕組みがあるのかしら。と。

Comment: [JSR 107: JCACHE - Java Temporary Caching API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107)のようなキャッシュ機構を利用するとかでしょうか。

Comment: javax.cache。 これは利用するプログラム側は Preferences と同じ感じ (key-value 型のアクセス) でしょうか。 質問内容とは別に、おもしろそうな API ですね。

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteなどのファイル型データベースを使うことが一般的ではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど。 あらかじめ空のファイル型データベースを作っておいて、静的リソースとして組みこんでおき、実行時に更新アクセスさせるという形ですね。

Comment: ただ、多数のファイルやディレクトリ多階層などをあつかいたい場合、あらためてファイル管理処理を作らねばならないことと、ファイル型データベースは大抵格納容量に限度があったりするのが難というところでしょうか。

Comment: ちなみに、ファイル型データベースでも構わないのですが、一般的にそのファイルはどこに置くものでしょうか。  絶対パスで指定するのではなく、相対パスで指定するとき、いろいろしらべてはいるのですが、java.lang.ClassLoader#getResource() が指すパスくらいしかないのではないかと思っています。 これは、Java の .class ファイルが置かれるパスで、なんとなく違和を感じております。

Comment: Javaで実行ファイルを作成する場合、一般的にはjarファイルで作ると思われます。（※Windowsであればexeにラップすることもありますがそれについては言及しません）
jarファイルと同じディレクトリ内にDBファイルを作るという構成ではダメなんでしょうか？実行時のjarファイルのパスを取得する処理は書けますが。
参考：
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

あと、まさかとは思いますが実行ファイル内のデータを更新するという考えではないでしょうね…それはありえませんよ

Comment: なるほど、やや冗長ながらも jar ファイル配置ディレクトリは取得可能ということですね。ありがとうございます。

考えているのは、たとえば、現行のブラウザ ソフトなどでの閲覧履歴の複数端末間同期のようなものです。 ただ、そのようなものは恐らくはサーバー・クライアントのシステムをきちんと組んで、ローカル・リモート間のデータ同期機構を実装するところまでやらないといけないだろうと。 それならば、jar ファイルにすべて埋め込み、データも動的に更新して、別端末にはそのファイルをコピーするだけで同じ状態でアプリ実行ができるかなと。

Comment: jarファイル内に更新するファイルを置いた場合、（１）zip圧縮されたファイルを上書きで更新しなければならず、（２）実行ファイル内のデータを更新できる権限がそもそもあるかどうか不明、なため筋が悪い設計だと思います。

Comment: はい。 web での検索などをしても、jar ファイル自身でそのような動作をする仕組みというのはなかなか見つかりません。 一般的な設計ではないということはわかりました。 そこまで自分で組むのも相当面倒そうですし。

おそらくは、jar ファイルと同一のディレクトリ上に置く、のがよいのかなと、思っております。